# KrakenJs with Dust Template looping through object Error

Tags: node.js, dust.js, kraken.js

> I should Have got the else part but I am getting the error:  Expected end tag for cart.items but it was not found. At line : 21, column : 35. I don't know where is the problem everything is fine may be indentation error please look out the code and suggest me. thanks there is also attached screen shot of the error.
>   this is my dust file:

```
{>"layouts/master" /}
    {<body}
     <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Your Cart</h2>
            {?cart.items}
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {#cart.items}
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="books/details/{._id}">{title}</a></td>
                                <td>{.qty}</td>
                                <td> ${@math key="{.price}" method="multiply" operand ="{.qty}"}</td>
                                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        {/cart.items}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <h4> Total <strong>${cart.total}</strong></h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                       </div>
                </div>
                {:else}
                    <p>There is no Items in your cart</p>
            {/cart.items}
        </div>
     </div>

    {/body}
```

> this is my controller

```
    'use strict';

var Book = require('../models/bookModel');
var Category = require('../models/categoryModel');

module.exports = function (router) {
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        var cart = req.session.cart;
        var displayCart = {
            items: [], total: 0
        };

        var total = 0;
        //get total

        for(var item in cart){
            displayCart.items.push(cart[item]);
            total += (cart[item].qty * cart[item].price);
        }
        displayCart.total = total;

        res.render('cart/index', {cart: displayCart});
    });
 });
```

> I am Getting this error:

[image: this is error screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

The math helper should be closed. E.g:

```
{@math key="{.price}" method="multiply" operand ="{.qty}" /}
```